# Powershell - WMI & AD Objects

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Can someone please show me a solution to the following problem or a better way to approach it - all I am trying to do is return some information about a selected server and contain the AD `Description` Field:

```powershell
$cred = Get-Credential -Credential "test_user"
$servername = "servername"

[wmi]$os = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $servername -Credential $cred
[wmi]$cs = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem -ComputerName $servername -Credential $cred
###[wmi]$ad = Get-ADComputer $servername -Properties Description -Credential $cred | Select-Object -Property description

 [hashtable]$osProperties = @{
    'Description' = $ad;
    'OSVersion'=$os.version;
    'OSBuild'=$os.buildnumber;
    'SPVersion'=$os.servicepackmajorversion;
    'Model'=$cs.model;
    'Manufacturer'=$cs.manufacturer;
    'RAM'=$cs.totalphysicalmemory / 1GB -as [int];
    'Sockets'=$cs.numberofprocessors;
    'Cores'=$cs.numberoflogicalprocessors;
    'SystemType'=$cs.SystemType}

$osproperties
```

Which returns:

```powershell
Manufacturer                   VMware, Inc.                                                                                                                                                                          
RAM                            4                                                                                                                                                                                     
OSVersion                      6.1.7601                                                                                                                                                                              
SystemType                     x64-based PC                                                                                                                                                                          
SPVersion                      1                                                                                                                                                                                     
Cores                          2                                                                                                                                                                                     
Model                          VMware Virtual Platform                                                                                                                                                               
OSBuild                        7601                                                                                                                                                                                  
Sockets                        2
```

But if I unselect the line `get-adcomputer` I get the following error:

```powershell
Cannot convert value "@{description=PROD - Portsmouth - VM - W2K8R2 Monitoring Server}" to type "System.Management.ManagementObject". Error: "Cannot convert the "@{description=PROD - Portsmouth - VM - W2K8R2 
Monitoring Server}" value of type "Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADComputer" to type "System.Management.ManagementObject"."
At line:12 char:2
+  [wmi]$ad = Get-ADComputer $servername -Properties Description -Credential $cred ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

Comment: Remove [wmi] before the variable $ad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 issues that I see. First is the one that [notjustme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3515885/notjustme) pointed out. You are trying to cast the output of `Get-AdComputer` into a WMI object... hence the error.

On the same line you are returning and object with a description *property*. Two small changes in that line would make the rest of the code work as intended.

```
$ad = Get-ADComputer $servername -Properties Description -Credential $cred | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty description
```

**Side Note**

Look at your question and see what I did to format your code blocks. Using the "{}" button above the text box, to create the indentation, would save you a lot of time.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and also the advice on code blocks. Cheers Matt